# QT error with copy file function

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a QT code to copy the whole content from sourcefile to destfile. With small-size files, it runs successfully, but with large-size files (for example, a video with 700MB of size), after process of copy, the destfile only had 2Kb of size.

This is the code of Copy routine, which does the copying process:

```
void Copy(QString destfile, QString sourcefile)
{
    qint64 bufSize = 100*1024*1024;//100 MB
    char *buf = new char [bufSize];
    //qint64 dataSize;
    QFile sfile(sourcefile), dfile(destfile);
    if (!sfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) || !dfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error";
        return;
    }
    while (!sfile.atEnd())
    {
        sfile.read(buf, bufSize);
        dfile.write(buf);
    }
    sfile.close();
    dfile.close();
    qDebug() << "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dfile.write(buf);` will write [a null terminated string](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) to your file, not the entire array. You want to do :

```
dfile.write(buf, bufSize);
                  ^^^^
```

**Notes:**

- You probably want to check the returned value of this call to test how many bytes were actually written. Same for `sfile.read(buf, bufSize);`, test how many bytes were read (it could be less than `bufSize`).

Something like :

```
while (!sfile.atEnd())
{
    qint64 bytesRead = sfile.read(buf, bufSize);
    if(dfile.write(buf, bytesRead) < 0)
    // error ...
}
```

- Also, `buf` could be allocated on the stack, no `new` is needed here.

Comment: Wow, the code runs successfully now, thank you very much!

// I can't vote up for you because I don't have enough 15 reputation, sorry!